# SQL Function Error: The multi-part identifier "T.acKey" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this function :

```
create FUNCTION dbo.fPA_TodoKeyValues(@acKey varchar(255))
returns @retRecords table(acSubject char(30)) 
AS

begin
declare @doctype char(1) 
set @doctype = SUBSTRING(@acKey,1,1) 
--primercreate procedure [dbo].[pPA_MailJournalCreDoc]
if @doctype = 'F'--računi
  insert @retRecords(acSubject)
  select
   case when D.acSetOf='F' and D.acType = 'P' then M.acReceiver
        when D.acSetOf='F' and D.acType = 'I' then M.acIssuer
        else M.acReceiver     
   end 
 from 
   tHE_Move M 
   join tPA_SetDocType D on D.acDocType =M.acDocType  


if @doctype = 'M'--mailjournal  
  insert @retRecords(acSubject)
  select acSubject from tPA_MailJournal
 -- JOIN tPA_LinkMailMove
 return
end
```

I have to make a view like this

```
select acName,acsubject from vPA_ToDo T
cross join fPA_TodoKeyValues(T.acKey) tv
```

But when I run this code I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The multi-part identifier
>   "T.acKey" could not be bound.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? There is only one field named `acKey` in the table.

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Non ANSI SQL there...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT
  acName,
  acsubject,
  * 
FROM vPA_ToDo T
OUTER APPLY fPA_TodoKeyValues(T.acKey)
```

Answer (score 2):

The procedure created `return`s a table. Hence you will have to `select` values from it as you would from a table, not as a `scalar` value.

```
select acName,acsubject from vPA_ToDo T
cross join
(select * from fPA_TodoKeyValues(T.acKey)) tv
```